# Mobilefirst Procedure invocation error. Ecma Error: TypeError:

Tags: jakarta-ee, ibm-mobilefirst

We have deployed war file with class and libraries but we are currently having issue on class it will return.

> Ecma Error: TypeError: [JavaPackage
>   com.ibm.cio.authenticate.Bluepages] is not a function, it is object.
>   (2015-02-24T23:52:55.169Z/663a1bef97ce5a75c64441102c8a35c23628502c/ServicesAuthAdapter-impl.js#73)

Our websphere is running in java 1.6 and development is 1.7
What would be possible solution?

Should degrade our development or upgrade websphere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will indeed happen when the Java used for the development environment is different than the Java version of the production/test environment.

Ensure that both use the same (whichever version that you most prefer).
Note that it is not enough to simply use Java X in the development machine - you need to also verify that Eclipse is setup to use that level of Java.

Take a look at Eclipse preferences > Java > Compiler, and Java > Installed JREs.

Comment: We solved the problem by upgrading to 1.7 java. Many Thanks Idan.

Comment: I am having same problem and the java version in development environment is 1.7.0_25 and in production/test environment 1.7.0_55 both are 64bit